# Taking byte[] value for EditText String input by user

Tags: java, android

I want to input a String and I want to get the byte[] value for it If I give a fixed value to the String like this:

```
String myinput = "SampleString";
byte[] keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

I am able to get the byte[] value but if i take input from edit text like:

```
String myinput = "SampleString";
mEdit1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
myinput = mEdit1.getText().toString();
keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

Then i do not get the byte[] value.

Here is one section of the code where byte[] value is needed:

```
public   Key generateKey() {

    byte[] keyValue;
    String aeskey = "ASecureSecretKey";
    mEdit1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    aeskey = mEdit1.getText().toString();
    keyValue = aeskey.getBytes();

Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, algorithm);
return key;
}
```

This is working fine when String has a fixed value but when the EditText editable is converted toString() and then .getBytes() is used i dont get the byte[] value.

Comment: Why not, May be you don't have anything entered in `EditText`?

Comment: I have entered "SampleString" as input in EditText and it still is not getting the byte[] value. Very Strange problem, must be some way to fix it.

Comment: what will be the value of `keyValue` then ? have you tried Logging ?

Comment: Try `byte[] keyValue = myinput.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);` once.

Comment: Write  `String aeskey = mEdit1.getText().toString();` and tell the value of `aesKey`. *Remember declaration and assignments are in same line*.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `EditText` is empty. Either you have to use `setText()` method to set text to `EditText` or use `text="SampleString"` in your xml.

Try this,

```
String myinput = "SampleString";

mEdit1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
mEdit1.setText(myinput);

myinput = mEdit1.getText().toString();
keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

your EditText field is most probably empty.

```
String myinput = "SampleString";
mEdit1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
myinput = mEdit1.getText().toString();
keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

Check null for `myinput` before getting bytes .